# Custom Zabbix LLD Data - Formatting &| Accessing

Tags: zabbix

**Purpose:**

Gather PHP-FPM metrics on a server with multiple versions and multiple pools per version

**config file:**

/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agent2.d/userparameter_php_fpm.conf

**config file contents:**

UserParameter=phpstuff,/usr/local/bin/php /php-status/getphpstuff.php --full

**sample command from zabbix server:**

zabbix_get -s myserv.com -k phpstuff

**JSON output of command:**

```
    "data": [
        {
            "{#VERSION}": "7.2.34",
            "{#PID}": "19495",
            "{#CPUPCT}": "0.0",
            "{#MEMPCT}": "0.0",
            "{#POOLNAMES}": [
                "nobody",
                "one",
                "two"
            ],
            "{#POOLCOUNT}": 3,
            "{#CHILDPROCCOUNT}": 10,
            "{#CHILDCPUTOTAL}": "45.0",
            ... 
        },
        {
            "{#VERSION}": "7.3.25",
            "{#PID}": "19368",
            "{#CPUPCT}": "0.0",
            "{#MEMPCT}": "0.0",
            "{#POOLNAMES}": [
                "nobody73",
                "fifty"
            ],
            "{#POOLCOUNT}": 2,
            "{#CHILDPROCCOUNT}": 0,
            "{#CHILDCPUTOTAL}": 0,
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

**The goal:**

To create discovery rule to make ?applications for each version which will have items for each of the stats under that version (and set graphs and triggers etc)

**The question:**

I can create the initial discovery rule, and get it to make the items/apps for the versions:

```
Name: PHPStuff
Type: Zabbix Agent
Key: phpstuff
```

With the prototype (or something like):

```
Name: PHP-FPM Version {#VERSION}
Type: Zabbix Agent
Key: phpfpm.info.masterprocesslist[{#VERSION}]
Type: Text
App Prototype: PHP {#VERSION}
```

But I cannot get at any of the other returned information.

Do I need to reformat the output? Or am I missing something basic?

Zabxix 5.2b1 Server + Zabbix Agent 2

Comment: Try without `"data": `, like just an array `[ { "{#STUFF}": "value" } ]`. See for example output from `zabbix_agent2 -t vfs.fs.discovery` - there's no "data:" there, just the array. You can select the discovery rule and trigger it manually - does it show an error or something?

Comment: The LLD is just a list: in your case, a list of PID. On top of that list you build a number of item prototypes, where you read data using another UserParameter. The `data` part is correct, and it's just the former/deprecated LLD format: still valid.

Comment: TY, removed "data" and it still works. Maybe I am not understanding zabbix correctly - but I cannot seem to reference the rest of the passed array of keys in any kind of "item prototype".  All of the built in functions call other functions that take parameters. I can refactor to do this, it just seems like giving all the needed data for an update at once would be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution (the input from the comments to the question helped a lot), posting here to hopefully help anyone else with what turned out to be just a fundamental misunderstanding of how Zabbix can ingest data (NOT as a giant block of JSON, incidentally). The documentation was frustrating since it usually just dealt with things that were built-in versus how to structure your data return for custom data, and I never really got the core concepts (though they now make sense)

1. Discovery Rule

Think of this as basically just taking an array of unique items to use as key(s) to get OTHER data (at least in the use case of the question I asked). So if Discovery Rule gets back the following:

ex.

```
[
    {
        "{#PHPVERSION}": "7.2.34"
    },
    {
        "{#PHPVERSION}": "7.3.25"
    }
]
```

I can then use those fields ({#PHPVERSION}) as a kind of built-in macro to use in prototypes.

If I now understand this correctly, you can expand this list of initial data with more information that might be needed to get the data you need for prototypes:

```
[
    {
        "{#PHPVERSION}": "7.2.34",
        "{#PHPAWESOME}": "yes"
    },
    {
        "{#PHPVERSION}": "7.3.25",
        "{#PHPAWESOME}": "no"
    }
]
```

In any case, in the PHP script I wrote to pass back data to Zabbix, I re-wrote the bits that output so I can use UserParameter(s) in a config file to extract the specific data I need - ex.

```
UserParameter=php.info.versions,/usr/local/bin/php /phpinfoscript/phpinfo.php --versions
```

Returns the list above in JSON, which data will be used for...

1. Prototypes

Prototype keys must all be unique, and since I cannot pass back all the data at once, I have be able to make unique calls for each piece of data. A sample prototype that I now have:

```
Name: PHP {#PHPVERSION} - PID
Type: Zabbix Agent
Key: php.info.processdata[{#PHPVERSION},"pid"]
...
Application Prototypes: PHP {#PHPVERSION}  // so all the data gets grouped correctly
```

The User Parameter looks something like:

```
UserParameter=php.info.processdata[*],/usr/local/bin/php /phpinfoscript/phpinfo.php --processs=$1 --getdata=$2
```

Where the data in the array in the Key at the end is passed to the positional arguments $1 and $2.

Repeat for each piece of data, using unique Keys for each.

Of note, the discovery rule probably does an iteration for each group of data given to it, so if I had needed to use {#PHPAWESOME} in the key to get other data, or name things, that should work as well.

The results work are exactly what I was going for - and honestly it would be nice if you could pass a block of data to get parsed - but it is what it is.